# Is it necessary to create sxa cores in solr 6.6.2

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search, sxa-search

I am Newbie to Sitecore 9.0.1.
I am building a SXA site for search functionality. Setting up of Sitecore and Solr 6.6.2 is done and I have installed SXA 1.7. Does the cores should be created for SXA separately in Solr?
For ex. `sitecore_sxa_master_index`.

If yes please explain the importance of creating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create SXA indexes in Solr.

Here is explanation how to do this copied from SXA 1.7 installation guide ( [https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/C9C535C21F8A4455BCF1F7F6C7AB1D1D.ashx?date=20180906T111805](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/C9C535C21F8A4455BCF1F7F6C7AB1D1D.ashx?date=20180906T111805) ):

Each index should have its own core, therefore for each custom index you wish to create for SXA, you must create a core.
To create your SOLR SXA core:

1. Duplicate core directory created for `sitecore_master_index` (or `company_name_master_index`) twice and rename to:

- `sitecore_sxa_master_index`
- `sitecore_sxa_web_index`

2. In those two folders, remove everything besides the `conf` directory.
3. On the Solr web interface, click `Core Admin` and click `Add Core` to add `sitecore_sxa_master_index`. Do the same for `sitecore_sxa_web_index`
4. In Sitecore, log in to the `Launchpad` and open the `Control Panel`.
5. In the `Indexing` section, click `Indexing Manager`.
6. In the `Indexing Manager` dialog box, select `sitecore_sxa_master_index` and `sitecore_sxa_web_index`, and click `Rebuild`

Why do you need this? SXA uses those indexes for it's functionality. If you don't create the cores, it will throw exceptions when you try to use it.

Comment: after creating cores in solr i didnt get a newly created sxa indexes in sitecore indexing manager.Is there anything else need to be configured in sitecore @Marek Musielak

Comment: @Vinaya try to keep single question in your Stack Exchange posts. If you have any other questions, create a new post and explain in details what have you done and what's the issue.